# Optimizar recorrido de nodos de XML en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, xml

Estoy realizando una aplicación para extraer datos de un xml y a través de ellos clasificar los documentos en diferentes carpetas. Uso el XmlNodeList y el XmlElement para sacar el atributo de los elementos pero lo hago con dos ciclos for para lograr eso, quisiera saber si es posible recorrer la estructura del xml para que dentro de un solo ciclo pueda obtener la "fecha" y "rfc". La aplicación lo estoy realizando en VB.NET

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Extructura XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" fecha="2017-09-29T10:52:53">
    <elemento rfc="XXXXXXXXXXXX" nombre="Nombre">

    </elemento>
</root>
```

Mi Código hasta ahora

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument

        Dim root As XmlNodeList
        Dim elemento As XmlNodeList

        Dim fecha As XmlElement
        Dim rfc As XmlElement
        doc = New XmlDocument()

        doc.Load("C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\file.xml")
        root = doc.GetElementsByTagName("root")
        elemento = doc.GetElementsByTagName("elemento")

        For Each fecha In root
            strFecha = fecha.GetAttribute("fecha")                
        Next

        For Each rfc In elemento
            strRFC = rfc.GetAttribute("rfc")                
        Next
```

Comment: podes mostrar la estructura de tu XML?

Comment: La estructura es la que  tengo arriba. Obvio dentro del root tendrá N nodos elemento, pero a mi me interesa obtener los atributos del nodo root y del nodo elemento. No se si me doy a antender

Comment: de cual de todos los nodos elementos? y donde?

Comment: Añadí una imagen en la pregunta, con una estructura de XML más real, lo único que quiero es extraer los datos encerrados en azul (fecha del nodo root y rfc del nodo elemento). Los demás datos no me interesa, solo esos dos

Comment: Hola, para recuperar el atributo fecha del nodo root, ya que es único, no necesitas un ciclo. Considerando lo que ya tenés podrías recuperar el dato de la siguiente forma:

        Dim strFecha As String
        strFecha = doc.GetElementsByTagName("root")(0).Attributes("fecha").Value.

El ciclo debería aplicarse solamente a la recuperación del atributo "rfc" para cada elemento (en tu código sería el segundo bucle For Each)

Saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto, nada mejor que linq to XML al rescate!!!

Veamos, hice un pequeño programa de ejemplo, con tu ejemplo y demostrando como obtener los valores que vos queres.

```
Dim nodoraiz As XElement
Dim Xml As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8""?><root xmlns:xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" fecha = ""2017-09-29T10:52:53""><elemento rfc = ""XXXXXXXXXXXX"" nombre = ""Nombre"" ></elemento ></root > "
Dim doc As XDocument = New XDocument()
doc = XDocument.Parse(Xml)
nodoraiz = doc.Element("root")
Dim fecha As String = nodoraiz.Attribute("fecha").Value

Console.WriteLine(fecha)

Dim rfc As String = nodoraiz.Element("elemento").Attribute("rfc").Value

Console.WriteLine(rfc)

Xml = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8""?><root xmlns:xsi = ""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" fecha = ""2017-09-29T10:52:53""><elemento rfc = ""XXXXXXXXXXX1"" nombre = ""Nombre"" ></elemento ><elemento rfc = ""XXXXXXXXXXX2"" nombre = ""Nombre"" ></elemento ></root > "
doc = XDocument.Parse(Xml)
nodoraiz = doc.Element("root")
fecha = nodoraiz.Attribute("fecha").Value

Console.WriteLine(fecha)

For Each v In nodoraiz.Elements("elemento")
    rfc = v.Attribute("rfc").Value
    Console.WriteLine(rfc)

Next
Console.ReadKey()
```

Lo que hacemos es basicamente, aprovecharnos que LINQ ya sabe como leer un xml, y en base a eso ir obteniendo las partes que queremos. Para Linq, todo nodo es un elemento (XElement). entonces de esa forma, podemos obtener el nodo raiz, y de ahi ir buscando las otras cosas que necesitamos.

Como no esta claro si elemento puede o no aparecer mas de una vez, se incluye otro XML con un for each, que en ese caso permitiria obtener ese valor mas de una vez.

Comment: Gracias, en efecto funciona de esta manera.